# Pandas conditional counting by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date

I want to count all orders done by each customer at each order date, to find out how many orders were done at the time of each order.

Input:

[image: customer_id order_id order_date 27501235 163595958 2018-12-14 27501235 165810252 2019-01-05]

Expected output:

[image]

The following code works but is extremely slow. Taking upwards of 10 hours for 100k+ rows. There is certainly a better way.

```
orders_total = []

for y,row in df_dated_filt.iterrows():
    orders_total.append(df_dated_filt[(df_dated_filt["order_id"] != row["order_id"]) & 
    (df_dated_filt["customer_id"] == row["customer_id"]) & 
    (pd.to_datetime(df_dated_filt['order_date'])<pd.to_datetime(row['order_date']))]["order_id"].count())

df_dated_filt["orders_total"] = orders_total
```

Comment: Can you add some example data by doing df_dated_filt.head(20) and pasting this to your question?

Comment: minor optimization: do the datetime conversion before the for-loop. Also, I think you want to group by customer_id and do a `cumsum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) to get dates in ascending order then [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) to enumerate groups in order:

```
df['orders_total'] = df.sort_values('order_date').groupby('customer_id').cumcount()
```

`df`:

```
   customer_id  order_id order_date  orders_total
0            1        12 2019-01-06             1
1            1        22 2019-01-01             0
2            2        34 2018-05-08             0
3            2        33 2018-05-12             1
4            2        38 2018-05-29             2
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'order_id': [12, 22, 34, 33, 38],
    'order_date': ['2019-01-06', '2019-01-01', '2018-05-08', '2018-05-12',
                   '2018-05-29']
})
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])

df['orders_total'] = (
    df.sort_values('order_date')
        .groupby('customer_id')
        .cumcount()
)

print(df)
```

Edit
Assuming same dates should have the same value per group via [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas-series-rank):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'order_id': [15, 12, 22, 34, 33, 38],
    'order_date': ['2019-01-06', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-01',
                   '2018-05-08', '2018-05-12', '2018-05-29']
})
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])

df['orders_total'] = (
        df.sort_values('order_date')
        .groupby('customer_id')['order_date']
        .rank(method='dense').astype(int) - 1
)
```

`df`:

```
   customer_id  order_id order_date  orders_total
0            1        15 2019-01-06             1
1            1        12 2019-01-06             1
2            1        22 2019-01-01             0
3            2        34 2018-05-08             0
4            2        33 2018-05-12             1
5            2        38 2018-05-29             2
```

Comment: I also have a column with "order_paid" (0 or 1) how would I count those together until each order date?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. It also sounds like you have an additional question about a DataFrame which includes more columns than you have shown in this question. I recommend you post a __new__ question that includes this additional condition and information, complete with sample input and desired output so that you have more space than the comments to be able to clearly define the issue, and can benefit from everyone's approach to solving your issue not just my own.